# IIS 7.0 - Enabling FTP publishing for 3 subdomains bound to a same IP address

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have 3 web applications in IIS 7.0, they're bound to different subdomains of a same domain, same IP address.

The problem is that I enabled FTP publishing for the 3 web applications (in order to publish from Visual Studio 2010), but it seems like I need to stop the 3 FTP sites and just start the FTP site to publish to, for it to work correctly.

Otherwise, the published files end up in the incorrect web application folder (for example, when I publish the SUB1 web app, it ends up in the folder mapped to SUB3).

What could I be doing wrong? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - when binding FTP sites to virtual hosts, the username becomes hostname|username . So following the above examples, that'd be sub1.example.com|administrator . Many thanks.